# Generate a random array in C

Tags: c, openvms

I'm developing in C using OpenVMS, I've done a code that put in a 1001 (0-1000) elements array, 1000 (0-999) random numbers between 0 and 50. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main(){
    int vet[1000], fre[50];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
        vet[i]=(rand()%51);
    }

    for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
        printf("%d\n", vet[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
        fre[vet[i]]=fre[vet[i]]+1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<51;i++){
        printf("The number %d  was generated %d times\n", i, fre[i]);
    }
}
```

When I show how much times each number was generated, I saw that the number 50 has a big number, sometimes more than double than others numbers, someone can help me?

**SOLVED Code that works** I must use srand() for now

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main(){
        int vet[1000], fre[51] = {0};
        int i;

        srand(time(NULL));

        for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
                vet[i]=(rand()%51);
        }

for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
printf("%d\n", vet[i]);
}

        for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
                        fre[vet[i]]=fre[vet[i]]+1;
        }

        for(i=0;i<51;i++){
                printf("The number %d  was generated %d times\n", i, fre[i]);
        }
}
[EOB]
```

**Thank you all**

Comment: The `rand()` PRNG is of very low quality. You'd better search for a better one, for example the [Mercenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) generator, if you'd require a high quality PRN stream. If [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/) compiles on OpenVMS, it comes with many PRNGs. As a last resort, OpenVMS supports the `drand48` PRNG. On a side node, `fre` is never initialised (to all 0's).

Comment: I' ve never used these other, I'll watch them this night, thank you! ;)

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75523944/6013016)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    int vet[1000], fre[50];


    for(i=0;i<51;i++){
            printf("The number %d  was generated %d times\n", i, fre[i]);
    }
```

Problem 1: You declare `fre` to have 50 elements, but you use 51.

Problem 2: `fre` isn't initialised.

```
int vet[1000], fre[51] = {0};
```

should give you reasonable output.

Comment: Why 51? The array doesn't start from 0? so when I write array[50] are 0,1,2,...,49,50?? the total is 51, I don't understand if I write 51 I can put in the array 52 elements, I' m wrong?

Comment: No, `type array[N];` declares an array of `N` elements of type `type`. The valid indices are `0` to `N-1`. So `int fre[50];` gives you indices 0 to 49. To use index 50, you need 51 elements.

Comment: Ok thank you now works!! Why showed me so a big number at 50? What happened?

Comment: @AlessioMTX A lot of things could have happened. Reading/writing past the array bounds is undefined behaviour, so what actually happened depends on the implementation, compiler options, ... . Possibly you just wrote to and read an unused memory slot containing garbage, or a stack protector, or the reurn address, I don't know.

Comment: @Joze Actually, it's better if the code segfaults upon undefined behaviour, IMO. If it does, it's a clear message, if it doesn't, you may not notice that there's anything wrong at all.

Comment: I was obviously joking ! I totally agree !

Comment: Segfault is a type of error you got for different reasons such as access violation. In your case, you had huge probability of getting this error. When you got this error, your program will totally crash ! 

More information about it here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Every C programmer have faced this error, at least once ! :)

Comment: Oh yes, it happened to me XD, but I didn't know that this was his name!

Answer (score 3):

```
int vet[1000], fre[50];
```

Your vet[] array has 1000 entries, not 1001. fre[] has 50, not 51. If you are generating numbers from 0 to 50, you need to declare fre[] as fre[51];

You also never clear your fre[] array before accumulating the results.

Comment: The array doesn't start from 0? so when I write array[50] are 0,1,2,...,49,50?? the total is 51, I don't understand

Comment: Arrays start from zero, but the number is the number of elements, not the maximum index. So fre[50] gives fre[0] .. fre[49]

Comment: By indexing off the end of your array, you were accessing memory used by something else, with unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

1) Initialize your variables before you use them:

```
int vet[1000] = {0};
int fre[50] = {0};
```

2)  You're checking for values outside the array size:

```
for(i=0;i<51;i++){
```

should be:

```
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
```

Your array `fre[50]` has elements `fre[0]` through `fre[49]`. So you want your count to start at 0 and go to `<50`, ie 49.

3) You're generating numbers outside your array size:

```
vet[i]=(rand()%51);
```

should be:

```
vet[i]=(rand()%50);
```

`rand() % x` will generate a number between `0-(x-1)`, if your array is size `50` then its elements are `0`-`49`, which means you need to pick `%50` or else you'll go over the array size when assigning with: `fre[vet[i]]=fre[vet[i]]+1;`

4) Keep in mind that [rand() function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) generates pseudo-random output, so there's always the chance it won't be as "random" as you wanted.

---

**EDIT**
Ok, your comment: `2) No because I'm checking also 0` makes me think you don't understand how arrays work:

```
int fre[50] = {0};
```

gives you an array of 50 elements. The index of arrays start at 0 and go to [number of elements - 1], such that:

```
first element -->fre[0], fre[1], fre[2], ..., fre[48], fre[49] <-- last element
```

If you want to record values from 0 to 50 *inclusive* you need 51 elements in your array:

```
int fre[51] = {0};
```

So both of these:

```
for(int i=0; i<50; i++)    and    for(int i=0; i<51; i++)
```

start at 0, and run through each element, but the former works on `fre[50]` (fifty elements from 0 to 49) and the latter works on `fre[51]` (fifty one elements, from 0 to 50)

Comment: 3) If I do %50 I have number from 0 to 49

Comment: 2) No because I'm checking also 0

Comment: @AlessioMTX - yup, you have to do that so you don't overflow your array of `fre[50]`. If you want to do numbers from 0-50 you have to increse the size of `fre` by 1.

Comment: I have done int fre[51] as Daniel and Jason told me. And now works. I haven't any overflow.

Comment: 37
20
25
24
40
36
0
50
49
27
23
These are some numbers and in the 1000 elements I have min 0 max 50

Comment: No I understand how array works, if I put 50 instead of 51 the run will show me until The number 49 was generated X times