# Array of random numbers using C program

Tags: c

Im new to C program and I am required create 100  random numbers between 50 and 70, and store them in an array of double. How do I start?

Comment: Have you written a "Hello world" program in C yet ?

Comment: Please try to at least attempt a solution, even in pseudo-code. Do you have any knowledge of C?

Answer (score 13):

Create an array:

```
int my_array[100];
```

Seed the random number generator

```
srand(0);
```

Loop over your array and fill it up!:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    my_array[i] = rand();
}
```

That's a start. However, the range of rand() is much larger than the range of random numbers you want. There are many ways to narrow the range. If you don't care about the numbers being *perfectly* random, you can use the modulo operator, where `13 % 10 = 3`.

This is for `int`s. I want to leave some fun for the reader.

Comment: That's not truly random. Seed with `srand(time(NULL))` so you don't get the same sequence of random numbers each time. See here: www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/#example

Comment: Why would you declare `i` outside `for` operator?

Answer (score 8):

If the number is between 50 and 70, then I would say, try modulo and the rand() function of c. 
So firstly since you will want yo use random numbers, I would advice including the standard library.
Do:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>`

double bal[100];

for (int f = 0; f < 100 ;f++) {
    bal[f] = (rand() % 20) + 50;
}
```

The reason why I modulo 20 is because the difference between 50 and 70 is 20 so, if you assume 50 is zero then 70 will be 20 and so any number we will produce will be between these numbers. Hope it helps! */

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to range the `rand` function:

```
rand() % (max_number + 1 - minimum_number) + minimum_number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void gen_random_numbers(int *array, int len, int min, int max){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
}

int main() {
    system("cls");
    srand(time(0));

    int numbers[100] = {};
    gen_random_numbers(numbers, 100, 50, 70);
    // create 100 arrays, each of them is in range of [50, 70]
    
    return 0;
}
```