# C: filling an array with random numbers in a range

Tags: c, arrays, random

I am trying accomplish the following tasks using C and arrays:

This is what I could do for now. I also need to print the output. What should I do or edit, thanks.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("How many elements in array?:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array0[n];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
      array0[i]= rand()%9 + 1;
    }

    int array1[10];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
      array1[i]= 0;
    }
    int index;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
      index = array0[i];
      array1[index-1]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that `rand()%9 + 1` will generate pseudo random numbers in the range [1,9].

Comment: @Bob__ I guess, that's fine. Because, the upper limit is not included unless stated otherwise.

Comment: You know how to loop over all entries of your `array1`. What exactly is your problem with printing them?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75523944/6013016) is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments , if you want number in range `1 to 10` :

```
array0[i]= rand()%10 + 1;
```

I suggest `int array1[10]={0};` instead of this loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
  array1[i]= 0;
}
```

and here is complete code with printing:

```
int main()
{
int n;
printf("How many elements in array?:");
scanf("%d",&n);
int array0[n];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
  array0[i]= rand()%10 + 1;//for your range
}

int array1[10]={0};

/*for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
  array1[i]= 0;
}*/
int index;
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
  index = array0[i];
  array1[index-1]++;
}
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("number %d appears:%d\n", i + 1, array1[i]);
    }
}
```

also as @Ardent Coder said add `srand(time(NULL));` bfeore `rand()` to  generate different random numbers at different runtimes.

Comment: Please note that `int array1[10]={0};` isnt necesarelly faster since `array1` is a local (auto) variable. You should check [Difference in initializing and zeroing an array in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453432/difference-in-initializing-and-zeroing-an-array-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, you just need to print the output after that:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
    printf("\n%d appears %d times", i, array1[i - 1]);
```

**Note:**

1. It would be better to add `srand(time(NULL));` once before calling `rand()` so that your code can generate different random numbers at different runtime.
2. `rand() % 9 + 1` will generate numbers in the range [1, 9]. So `int array1[10];` can be changed to `int array1[9];` to save some memory. But if you need numbers in the range [1, 10] then don't change that but change `rand() % 9 + 1` to `rand() % 10 + 1` and let the printing loop run upto 10.

Comment: Didn't he said numbers between 1 and 10? Shouldn't the formula be `rand()%10 + 1` instead of making the array smaller ?

Comment: @Tudor See my comment below the question. I was taught that, "between a and b" = [a, b). Also in statistics, frequency intervals are divided with this convention. I am not sure, but OP can clarify otherwise. Or, I'll edit my answer with this update.